# JSch connect to remote server and sudo su

Tags: java, unix, jsch

i am new to JSch. please let me know how to connect to remote server and perform sudo su and move file from one path to another inside remote server.

1. Connect to Remote server : ssh myName@server.remote.com
2. sudo su -homeUser
3. cp /one/two/testFile.txt /one/testFile.txt
4. if found (ls -lrt /one/testFile.txt), echo file copied.
5. disconnect

please suggest piece of code to do the above using JSch library

```
public void exec(){
Jsch jsch = new JSch();
try{
Session session = jsch.getSession(user,host,22);
session.setPassword("password");
UserInfo ui = new MyUserInfo();
session.setUserInfo(ui);
session.connect();
Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand("sudo su -homeUser");

Channel.connect();
Channel.disconnect();



session.disconnect();
}Catch(Exception e )
{
}
}
public static class MyuserInfo implements Userinfo
{

@override
public String getPassword()
{
return "password";
}
@override
public String getPaspharse(){
return "yes";
}

@override
public boolean promtPassword(String arg0)
{
return true;
}
@override
public boolean promtPasspharse(String arg0)
{
return true;
}

@override
public boolean promtYesorNo(String arg0)
{
return true;
}
@override
public boolean showMessage(String arg0)
{

}
}
```

Comment: i dont want any GUI. i am going to run this java code from a local unix server.

Comment: What you have tried?@prabhu

Comment: i have added what i have tried. please find it useful.